# Как можно отправлять каждый день новый excel файл в telegram в виде фотографии

Tags: telegram, excel, png

У меня есть папка, в которой каждый день автоматический создаётся новый excel файл с отчетом.

Есть ли какой-то способ передать этот файл в определенную группу в телеграмме в виде фотографии, а потом удалить этот файл с ПК?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. предлагаю разбить задачу:

- создание картинки из содержимого ексель файла
- публикация картинки в группу телеграмма
- удаление ексель файла

2. вероятно проще будет создать телеграмм бота

Исходя из подзадач, рекомендую определиться с языком программирования и списком используемых библиотек.